# Chrome: open a custom input interface on click

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to register the selection (may it be via a click or other ways) of a text field (of any kind) with my extension and open up a separate input interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a prompt...

```
<script>
function disp_prompt() {
  var fname=prompt("What is your name?");
  alert("Your name is " + fname);
}
</script>
<body onload=disp_prompt()>
```

If you want to have this popup onclick, You need to utilize a background page

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
```

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can capture the user interaction with JavaScript in a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html). And if by “separate input interface”, you’re referring to something within the browser, you can also inject UI or open a new page with a content script. If you’re referring to another app, you can launch one with native code in an [NPAPI plugin](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html).